# How to execute a Lambda function before a method is called in API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I need to execute some Lambda function for collecting statistics before any method from API gateway is called. Is it possible to achieve this in AWS? I am using proxy integration in Api Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the CDN level if you have one.
If you are using cloudfront then the steps could be,

1. Create a regional endpoint.
2. Set up own cloudfron distribution - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/
3. Handle the request with Lambda@Edge, add a trigger for Origin Request.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Unfortunately your solution is possible to implement only in "US East (N. Virginia)" region -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-add-triggers-lam-console.html

I can't change the region to US East (N. Virginia) so I need to look for other solutions.

Comment: may I know what kind of statistics are you looking to measure?

Comment: I want to count API requests which contain certain data, i.e. API requests which have  "personId" parameter set in body. I want to store these statistics in DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 1):

Few Ideas,

- If the requests may be whitelisted and blacklisted based on the parameter, lambda custom authorizor can be used to plug in the logic.
- if the statistics don't influence the business logic, then cloudwatch logs can be parsed (log insights or cloudwatch rules) and the statistics can be gathered.
- Aggregation pattern can be used for the statistics- either Gateway or Lambda level , but this will add additional latency for each requests.

Comment: Unfortunately CloudWatch is not an option for me. I need to extract tenantId field from the request. This is needed for my statistics.